# Pure-FTPd is running as root by default on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

I just installed Pure-FTPd (`pure-ftpd-1.0.30-1.el6.x86_64`) on my CentOS 6.5 server.

I'm using "virtual users", so the FTP users are disconnected from the system accounts.

Nevertheless, **the pure-ftpd daemon itself is running as root**, and all the uploaded files are root-owned.

On the manual I read that all the clients are chrooted to their home dir, but I'm a bit uneasy with the uploaded file being uploaded+owned by root. Should I change the pure-ftpd users or am I worrying for nothing?

**A few clarifications:**

1) I'm trying to do an assessment on the security of this configuration: if I find out that this default is safe, I'm more than happy to keep it as it is and don't mess with it

2) Buffer overflows are one of the aspect I worry about

Answer (score 0):

You're worrying for nothing, there's no possible way (that I'm aware of) to execute code inside an FTP chrooted shell (unless you have remote access to the system, i.e. SSH).

Comment: If process is running as root is possible to "evade" the chroot

Answer (score 0):

A quick review of the docs alludes to the ability to run "100% non-root" if you're feeling nervous why not look into that?